# IS ASA applicable on triangles on the sphere?

Tags: geometry, spherical-geometry

$ASA= \text{Angle-Side-Angle}$

I was wondering if $ASA$ still worked on triangles for the sphere. I have a pretty hard time visualizing triangles on the sphere because I know the sum of their interior angles can be more than $180^{\circ}$, which feels weird to me, since I am accustomed to triangles on the plane. I know $ASA$ works on triangles on the plane, as you can just find the third angle by subtracting the sum of the other angles from $180^{\circ}$, and then use the Law of Sines to find out the other side lengths. Would $ASA$ work on a triangle on a sphere? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Two spherical triangle with the same ASA are indeed congruent. A rotaion of the sphere that brings the same-size sides togethre also does this for the adjacent angles, hence for all sides and vertices.

Comment: It's also true on the hyperbolic plane, IIRC, by essentially the same argument - the key element is that there's still only a single line through a given point at a given angle with a given line through that point.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Indeed. Knowing a side ($\gamma$) and the two angles at either side ($A$ and $B$), we can use the dual Law of Cosines to get the third angle ($C$):
$$
\cos(C)=-\cos(A)\cos(B)+\sin(A)\sin(B)\cos(\gamma)
$$
Then, we can use the Law of Sines as usual to get the other sides.

Alternatively, we can use the same dual Law of Cosines to get
$$
\cos(\alpha)=\frac{\cos(A)+\cos(B)\cos(C)}{\sin(B)\sin(C)}
$$
and
$$
\cos(\beta)=\frac{\cos(B)+\cos(A)\cos(C)}{\sin(A)\sin(C)}
$$
Note that, unlike plane trigonometry, we can determine a spherical triangle by AAA.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know about the dual Law of Cosines. Very useful.

Comment: @SujaanKunalan: For every spherical triangle, with angles $A$, $B$, and $C$, and sides $\alpha$, $\beta$, and $\gamma$, there is a dual triangle with angles $\pi-\alpha$, $\pi-\beta$, and $\pi-\gamma$, and sides $\pi-A$, $\pi-B$, and $\pi-C$. Thus, for every spherical trig formula involving trig functions of sides and angles, there is a similar one with sides and angles exchanged.

Answer (score 2):

If you allow degenerate triangles, then no, otherwise yes.

If you try to draw edges at appropriate angles from the known side, then their intersection is almost always uniquely determined, and so the whole triangle is. Angles and side lenghts are invariant under rotations, so you can actually "move" one triangle to the other so that their known side matches, and then the other triangle edges have to follow the same great circles, thus having the same intersection point.

However, consider a case where your side is of length $\pi$ and the angles are $\frac{\pi}{2}$ – you know how the triangle looks like, but you don't know where the third point actually is. It is similar to when both angles are $0$, but here the shape can have actually non-zero area (which is different from the planar case).

This feels much like nit-picking, but nevertheless I hope it helps $\ddot\smile$

Comment: True also in plane  and hyperbolic geometry. A nit upon the nit is that the triangle is still uniquely determined as a set of points.  (+1)